# Using javascript LazyLoad with asset precompilation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, lazy-loading

So here's my problem. I'm using the [LazyLoad](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/) plugin for loading javascript files without blocking the page from rendering. This is how i'm using it:

```
LazyLoad.js(["/assets/jquery.js","/assets/another_js_file.js"],function () {
   some javascript code;
});
```

When I push my code to heroku my assets get precompiled and the their names change to:

another_js_file-97e27736199a78287129ad86d5aa6ae1.js
Which makes my LazyLoading break.

How can I LazyLoad the files when I don't know their final names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always disable fingerprinting for your assets in your config file (config/environments/production.rb):

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

Although this would affect your file versioning so only use if you can handle it in a different way or if you don't really need versioning for your app.

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for the answer, it worked. But not that i've turned the digest off I think Heroku is caching my assets.. I'm pushing new code and it doesn't seem to update in some of the asset files. Have any idea why that is?

Comment: Yes, the fingerprinting is the mechanism Heroku uses for avoiding issues with cached assets. You need to create your own way of file versioning if you want to prevent this from happening. If you do so, you can control which 'fingerprint' you add to your assets and then you can lazy load them by adding the fingerprint by default when requesting the assets. Take a look at rails documentation if you need further help on this topic, cause it's not a trivial one: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to turn off fingerprinting in production. Leave it set to true. Otherwise your assets will get cached and it will be hard to update them.

I'm doing something similar to you, and I've solved the fingerprinting problem by changing my .js file to .js.erb, and using the rails asset_path helper to generate the url to the js file. This way, the fingerprint gets incorporated.

Using your code above, try something like this: ( I assume your code is in a js file called foo.js:

```
//rename foo.js to foo.js.erb
LazyLoad.js(["<%= asset_path 'jquery.js' %>","<%= asset_path 'another_js_file.js'%>"],function () {
   some javascript code;
});
```

Then, when you upload to heroku (or run rake assets:precompile) , your foo.js.erb should get compiled into foo-97e27736199a78287129ad86d5aa6ae1.js  , and it will contain the correct references to jquery.js and another_js_file.js, including their fingerprints.

You may also need to add  those files to your asset list in environments/production.rb, or whatever env you are using:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(foo.js)
```